# C# XmlWriter.Create() - Access to path denied

Tags: c#

I want to write a new XML file to disk but the following code gives an error.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(@"C:\abc.xml"))
            {
                writer.WriteStartDocument();
                writer.WriteStartElement("Employees");
                writer.WriteEndElement();
                writer.WriteEndDocument();
            }            

            Console.ReadKey();       
       }
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Note: abc.xml does not already exist.

Comment: are you sure error is access to path denied? because in my PC I received "A required privilege is not held by the client." error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Obviously,** you don't have the right to access `C:`. Choose a path you have access to or run the application with higher privileges.

As a side note, for most scenarios, it's not recommended to use `System.Xml` anymore, use LINQ to XML (`System.Xml.Linq`) instead:

```
new XElement("Employees").Save("abc.xml"); // and a path that you have access to.
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the system, you need administrator rights to create files @C:\

Run VS instante as administrator or change code to

```
 using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("abc.xml"))
        {
            writer.WriteStartDocument();
            writer.WriteStartElement("Employees");
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndDocument();
        }
```

Comment: Just to explain the above code, the difference is that in this case the "abc.xml" file is created in the same directory as YourProgram.exe (bin/Debug or bin/Release), which is writable by user running VS

Answer (score 2):

Don't wanna necropost, but I just saw this post and I got the same error.

Turns out that the folder was set to:

- ReadOnly

This disallows C# to write to any of the files in your solution.

To fix this, go to:

- Right-Click on the main folder that houses all of your C# .sln files
- Go to Properties
- At the very bottom of the window will be a check named: Read-only (Only applies to files in folder)

Here is a link to what the above folder looks like:
[image: Properties]

Really stupid, but something easy to forget!

Answer (score 1):

You can not write file into `C:\` from VS without administrator mode. You need to run your application/VS in Admin mode to write file in `C:\`. Or you can create one folder in `C:\` and write file in that folder.

**CODE**

```
 using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(@"C:\folder\abc.xml"))
 {
           writer.WriteStartDocument();
           writer.WriteStartElement("Employees");
           writer.WriteEndElement();
           writer.WriteEndDocument();
  }
```

In above code you don't required to run application/VS in admin mode.

**Note:** C:\folder must exist otherwise it throws error.

If `C:\folder` not exist add below code before writing file.

```
if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(@"C:\folder") == false)
{
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\folder");
}
```

Comment: That's not true: the above code doesn't work without admin privileges.

Comment: Your code only works if `folder` already exists, which it doesn't... I *did* try before commenting.

Comment: You can check with below step: just open one notepad file and try to save it in C:\ you get error message. Now create one folder in C:\ and try to save notepad file. you can save it successfully because you can't save directly file in C:\ but you can save file after create folder (current login user has permission(write& read) on folder) in C:\ .

Comment: yes it's obvious folder must be there. I am not saying to save file without folder. I am just gave solution to save file C:\ without running VS/Application in admin mode.

Comment: @codesparkle Think a downvote is a little harsh here. I just gave alternate solution. I already mentioned in my answer to create folder in C:\ and after that save file.

Comment: Good clarification. But why not just create the folder? `Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\folder");` works, even without admin rights.

Comment: @codesparkle I mentioned C:\folder must exist with note in my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

For people who came here with exception

> XmlWriter.Create() - Access to path denied

And you have the privilege to the given path you have mentioned, then have to check your file name as well. I had the issue when I was trying to create a file with **no name** or with **no file extension**. For these cases as well we will get the above mentioned exception